# Processing an excel sheet with password

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have a web app which lets the user select the excel spreadsheet and does some processing against tables on sql server, adds new col. to sheet. in C#. sorry my bad, not using Interop but using DevExpress to process. they have a feature to process excel sheets. but it's not working on the password protected ones/
I am getting now excels with password protected how can i have the c# be told to ignore password?

Comment: Is there an error message when you try to manipulate the excel spreadsheet from C#?

Comment: You shouldn't be using Interop for a web app. It isn't supported by Microsoft

Comment: sorry i apologize indeed we cross that interop bridge and are using dev express.

Comment: This sounds like a question for the DevEx people (do they support working with password-protected Excel files?). You can't make C# "ignore" the passwords; you have to figure out how to supply the password needed in order to use the file. Again, does the DevEx product work with password-protected spreadsheet files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jetti has said, you should not use Office interop in a server environment.  There are many reason for that and they are listed by Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).  Instead, try something like [OOXML](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) (free) or [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com) (commercial).